# React app connect to the internal ip of the backend

Tags: reactjs, docker

I have a react app in the docker and nodejs backend both deployed in the VPC. 
I try to connect to the backend from the frontend using the internal IP and get the `Error in connection establishment: net:: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

I have no idea how react and frontend works. But I can run the curl from the frontend docker to the backend internal Ip. My question is, is this even possible?

Comment: Your react app runs on the client's browser, not in the docker container.

Comment: Well I build it outside of the docker and I copy the build folder to the docker and I use Nginx to run it. Does that mean that I can't use internal IP? tkausl

Comment: This means that where ever the react is being run isn't in the same network as the internal ip that your backend is defined at. I mean obviously very possible for a react app to run and communicate to a BE over a local ip, but odds are thats not what you want. I would recommend access the BE from your react app over the public ip

Comment: Note - when I say its very possible for a react app to communicate to a BE over a local/ 'internal' ip, Its only possible if the react app is being run on a machine within that network. Odds are thats not what you are doing, unless your building some internal tool that will on be accessed on your network and thats how you want to communicate.